# Mount user-specific folder on logon

Tags: windows, mount, login

There is a small network with an active directory, and there is one machine with RAID-1 storage. How can I mount a user-specific shared folder, for example:

```
\\NetworkStorage\Storage\%USERNAME%
```

when `%USERNAME%` performs logon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the **NET** command to mount a drive:

```
NET USE F: \\NetworkStorage\Storage\%USERNAME%
```

(Note that you need to use back slashes, not forward slashes)

This could be added to your logon script.

ALSO, you can specify a "home" drive for each user in his or her active directory profile.  This can be mounted **automatically**, or with the following command:

```
NET USE F: /HOME
```